# Why am I getting a {"location": null} when I try to convert a text/xml into an object?

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

I'm trying to understand the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) behavior, but something is going wrong and I'm not knowing how to find the problem. Here's a simple code that parses a string that contains the text of an XML:

```js
const xml = '<data>Hello World</data>'

const parser = new DOMParser()
const result = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')

alert(JSON.stringify(result))
```

As you can see, I'm getting a `{"location": null}`. Can someone explain to me what's wrong and what is this `location`? How can I parse this string into an object as the documentation suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseFromString` returns the document `object` that holds the parsed representation of text, like:

```js
const xml = '<data>Hello World</data>'

const parser = new DOMParser()
const result = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')

console.log(result)
```

You can see the complete object in the `console.log()`. As per your concerned about where the `"location": null` comes from so It is currently unclear what the URL of the returned document should be.

[image]

You can learn more about `parseFromString` from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Parsing-20120920/#widl-DOMParser-parseFromString-Document-DOMString-str-SupportedType-type).

Answer (score 2):

The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) returned from [`parseFromString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_XML) is not JSON, if you want to stringify the result, use an [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer).

```js
const xml = '<data>Hello World</data>';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
const docString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
console.log(docString);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use following script:-
Html-

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript -

```
<script>
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<data>Hello`enter code here` World</data>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>
```

It works as you want.

Answer (score -1):

From the Documentation-

> The DOMParser interface provides the ability to parse XML or HTML 
>   source code from a string into a DOM Document.

So, it is converting XML or HTML to DOM [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), not [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). For, this reason the result couldn't show any result by `alert(JSON.stringify(result))`

```
const xml = '<data>Hello World</data>'

const parser = new DOMParser()
const result = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')
console.log(result); 

Output:
#Document
<data>Hello World</data>
```

For your expected result, use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)

```
let s = new XMLSerializer();
console.log(s.serializeToString(result));
```